# Оптимизация и статические функции

Tags: c++, оптимизация

Вопрос навеян следующим утверждением:

> 7.14 Functions
>
> > Make functions static It is recommended to add the keyword static to
> >     all non-member functions that are not needed outside the module in
> >     which they are defined. The static declaration restricts the scope of
> >     the function to the current module (i.e. the current .cpp file). This
> >     enables the compiler to optimize across function calls. You cannot use
> >     this optimization for class member functions, because the keyword
> >     static has a different meaning for member functions.

[Источник](https://www.agner.org/optimize/optimizing_cpp.pdf)

Как работает оптимизация для статических функций?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Идея процитированного совета базируется на том, что в месте вызова функции с внутренним связыванием компилятору всегда доступно определение этой функции.

Поэтому, во-первых, компилятор всегда имеет возможность встроить вызов такой функции, если сочтет это необходимым.

Во-вторых, независимо от того, встраивается функция или нет, имея доступ к определению функции, компилятор имеет полное представление о ее поведении (например, какие элементы переданного агрегата она модифицирует, а какие нет), что дает ему возможность лучше оптимизировать вызывающий код.

```
static void foo(int a[])
{
  a[5] = 5;
  a[rand() + 1] = rand();
}

void bar()
{
  int a[100] = { 42 };
  foo(a);
  // Здесь компилятор знает, что `a[0]` по-прежнему `42`
}
```

В-третьих, компилятор имеет полное представление о всех контекстах вызова такой функции и может оптимизировать код функции с учетом особенностей этих контекстов. (При условии, что такая функция не является доступной снаружи косвенными средствами, т.е. через указатели)

```
static void foo(int a, int b)
{
  // Здесь компилятор знает, что `a` всегда четно, 
  // а `b` не превосходит `3`
}

...
foo(i * 2, 2);
...
foo(j * 4, 3);
...
// Других вызовов `foo` нет
```